# Downloaded string from Reddit page with is the same for about a minute straight of checking even though it should have changed

Tags: c#, json, garbage-collection, reddit

The following C# code downloads the JSON of a Reddit random page. It is correctly downloading and looping if the value found is not valid. However, the returned string is the same for about a minute straight of checking. Does anybody know if this is a memory problem, a Reddit API problem, or a webClient problem?

```
string src = "";
while(src.endsWith(<someString>))
{
    src = dl(<valid site>);
}

void dl(string st)
{
    string json = new WebClient().DownloadString(string);
    ...
    string src = <manipulation of json>;
    ...
    return src;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're fetching the same reddit url, you are hitting the akamai cache. While you can bypass the akamai cache by visiting `api.reddit.com` instead of `www.reddit.com`, your program *should* respect reddit's [API rules](https://github.com/reddit/reddit/wiki/API), which include, "don't hit the same page more than once per 30 seconds."

Comment: Thanks! I would of never figured that out!

Comment: I've found that this still doesn't work for accessing `api.reddit.com/random`

Comment: it's more like a minute or a little more. Also, the randomosity limited for some reason